# Difficulty extracting iphone configuration profile

Tags: ios, pem

I recently installed a profile on my iPhone, the profile was in the form of a .pem file. Having installed the certificate, I would like to know how to determine the exact location of the profile on the iOS filesystem. I have iFile installed so if anybody knows where profiles install on the iPhone please let me know.

Comment: im trying to find the location of the installed certificate so that i can reuse it on another ios device... The device is jailbroken so I can access the root directories on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `var/mobile/Library/ConfigurationProfiles/PublicInfo`. In there you'll find your certificates.